# Data Studio Community Connector error: The number of columns in the data does not match the number in the schema.

Tags: looker-studio

When I try to explore my data source fetched by a custom connector, I encounter a System error: 593d1fe0.

`The number of columns received in the data returned from the community connector does not match the number of columns requested by Data Studio`

But When I'm debugging my getData function, the result contains the same columns and same number of columns.

What can cause this kind of troubles ?
some screenshots of the debug view:

[image: the schema]

[image: the data (rows)]

Is my output structure correct ? is there something to consider regarding column names ?

Answer (score 6):

Data Studio does not request all the possible fields from `getData` function. Most of the times, Data Studio will request a small subset from available fields. The list of required fields will be passed in the `request` object when the `getData` call is made.

See [getData reference doc](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getdata) to understand the structure of `request` and `fields`.

Your `getData` response should not return all available fields. Rather, the response should return only the requested fields. See [example code](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/blob/master/stackoverflow-questions/main.js#L421) showing how you can filter the fields.

For additional help, you can try the official [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-connectors/) - *Step 10* is relevant to your question. You can also view more examples at the official [Data Studio Open Source repo](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/).

Comment: Hi @minhaz-kazi! Thank you for your help and tutorials. Doesn't this process slow down the execution? When `getData` takes only some of the required fields, it certainly should return to the function multiple times and refer to the API or source multiple times.

Comment: Most welcome! The execution timing will actually depend on the elements on your dashboard. e.g. if your schema has 60 fields and your dashboard has only one element with 2 fields, execution might actually be faster. This type of design also allows connectors to have a schema catering multiple endpoint instead of just one single instance of tabular data. A good example of this is the native Google Analytics connector. Furthermore, if you API supports filtering and aggregation, you will also get gains there.